Integer Overflow for UInt32 in Delphi
I use the following function to convert an AnsiString to an Uint32. The AnsiString is is composed of bitsream characters of 0 and 1.
I am using Delphi 12.1
function BinaryStringToUInt32(const binaryStr: AnsiString): UInt32;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  // Convert the binary value to an integer
  for i := 1 to Length(binaryStr) do
  begin
    Result := Result * 2 + Ord(binaryStr[i]) - Ord('0');
  end;
end;

However, I get an Interger overflow for high values close to the uint32 maximum range. How is this possible?
If I change the code to the following, it works fine:
function BinaryStringToUInt32(const binaryStr: AnsiString): UInt32;
var
  i: Integer;
  test: UInt64;
begin
  test := 0;
  // Convert the binary value to an integer
  for i := 1 to Length(binaryStr) do
  begin
    test := test * 2 + Ord(binaryStr[i]) - Ord('0');
  end;
  Result :=  UInt32(test);
end;

this code is probably more efficient and works as well:
function BinaryStringToUInt32(const binaryStr: AnsiString): UInt32;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Ensure input string length does not exceed 32 characters
  if Length(binaryStr) > 32 then
    raise Exception.Create('Input string exceeds 32 characters');

  Result := 0;
  // Convert the binary value to an integer
  for i := 1 to Length(binaryStr) do
  begin
    Result := Result shl 1; // Shift result left by one bit
    if binaryStr[i] = '1' then
      Result := Result or 1; // Set the least significant bit if current bit is '1'
  end;
end;


Your calculation
Result := Result * 2 + Ord(binaryStr[i]) - Ord('0');

is evaluated from left to right. Therefore it can happen that adding Ord(binaryStr[i]) overflows before Ord('0') is subtracted.
Enclosing Ord(binaryStr[i]) - Ord('0') in brackets should make it work.
Result := Result * 2 + (Ord(binaryStr[i]) - Ord('0'));

